How to get all elements with similar names that are not empty in a JSON?
I'm new here and I'm trying to use all the "ingredients" of this JSON (from an API) to show them on the screen, but I'm not sure how, since for each recipe the number of ingredients are different.
I tried concatenate the name in a loop and change the suffix number each time, but it does not work.
JSON
const dataCocktail = response.data.drinks[0];
while (dataCocktail.strIngredient+number) {
ingredients = ingredients.push(dataCocktail.strIngredient+number);
number++;
console.log(ingredients);
}


This looks like an Object, rather than JSON. It does not work, but what does it do? Is there an error in the console? Please update your question to include a minimal reproducible example.

Also, have you tried Object.keys()?

There are a lot of built-in ways to handle this. You can use Object.keys which will create an array of all of the keys in that json object, and then you can map over them with the map array method.
Object.keys(dataCocktail.strIngredient).map((k) => {
    const item = dataCocktail.strIngredient[k]
    console.log(`Item: ${item}`)
})

The docs on MDN will be your best friend with most things javascript or typescript.
